# Error: Please fix the version conflict

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

While using the dependencies shows error on either auth or on database.how to resolve this???

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
//here it shows error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'
```

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:4.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
```

to this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

all firebase dependencies need to be the same version

Comment: this helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you can use firebaseAuth and firebase Realtime database at the same time. But your gradle dependencies for firebase should be of same version.